# How to target all nodes of an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster with Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I've got an issue connecting to an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster (AMQ from Red Hat in fact) through Spring's `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`.

`DefaultMessageListenerContainer` makes use of only one connection, regardless of the number of consumers you specify through the concurrency parameter. The problem is that, in the cluster, there are 3 brokers configured at the moment (and, as a dev, I shouldn't care about the topology of the cluster).  Since here is only one connection consumers are only listening to one broker.

To solve the issue I disabled the cache (i.e. `setCacheLevel(CACHE_NONE)` in the factory).
It "solved" the problem because now I can see the connections distributing on all the nodes of the cluster but it's not a good solution because connections are perpetually dropped and recreated and that makes a lot of overhead at the broker side (it makes me think of a Christmas Tree :D).

Can you guys tell me what's the correct approach to handle this?
I trie using a `JmsPoolConnectionFactory`, but I didn't get any good results till now. I still have only one connection.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.4 with Artemis Starter.
You can find below a code snippet of the actual config.

(Side note, I don't use Spring autoconfig because i need to be able to switch between ActiveMQ Artemis and the old ActiveMQ "Classic" implementation).

```java
@Bean
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(config.getConcurrency());
    //Set this to allow load balancing of connections to all members of the cluster
    factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);

    final ExponentialBackOff backOff = new ExponentialBackOff(
    config.getRetry().getInitialInterval(), config.getRetry().getMultiplier());
    backOff.setMaxInterval(config.getRetry().getMaxDuration());

    factory.setBackOff(backOff);

    return factory;
}

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory(
    config.getUrl(), config.getUser(), config.getPassword());
}

DestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
    final ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue = new ActiveMQQueue(config.getQueue());
    return (session, destinationName, pubSubDomain) -> activeMQQueue;
}


@JmsListener(destination = "${slp.amq.queue}")
public void processLog(String log) {
    final SecurityLog securityLog = SecurityLog.parse(log);

    fileWriter.write(securityLog);
    logsCountByApplicationId.increment(securityLog.getApplicationId());

    if (elasticClient != null) {
        elasticClient.write(securityLog);
    }
}
```

The connection URL is:

```
(tcp://broker1:port,tcp://broker2:port,tcp://broker3:port)?useTopologyForLoadBalancing=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster can be configured so that any consumer on any node can consume messages sent to any node. Therefore, you shouldn't strictly need to "target all nodes" of the cluster with your consumer. Message redistribution and re-routing in the cluster should be transparent to your application. As you said, as a developer you shouldn't care about the topology of the cluster.

That said, the goal of clustering is to increase overall message throughput (i.e. performance) via horizontal scaling. Furthermore, every node in the cluster should ideally have sufficient producers and consumers so that messages aren't being redistributed or re-routed between cluster nodes as that's not optimal for performance. If you're in a situation where you have just a few consumers connected to your cluster then it's likely you don't actually *need* a cluster in the first place. A single ActiveMQ Artemis broker can handle millions of messages per second in certain use-cases.

Comment: Hi, 

Thx for your feedback first.

you are right on the fact that i don't really need a cluster for performance reasons.  The thing is i'm deploying in an HA environment with 3 fault domains 'containing' one node of the cluster each. 

I'm also not the only app using it.

That being said, i should be able to consume messages directly on the node where it comes even if the topology is able to redistribute the messages between the nodes (Here, it's a Network of broker topology) in order to avoid network overhead.  

That said, it may be i'm totally wrong in my approach :D

Comment: If you're not using a cluster for performance reasons then why do you need to "consume messages directly on the node where it comes...in order to avoid network overhead"? In order to do this you'd have to manually create and manage a connection to every node in the cluster. There's nothing in the client that would do this for you. As noted previously, the cluster is designed so that it can redistribute and re-route messages to consumers to avoid starvation specifically so that clients *don't* have to care about the cluster topology. I don't think what you're suggesting is a good approach.

Comment: The thing is i'm not the only one using this cluster.  The recommandation comes from our infra team saying we should produce/listen on all nodes...i suppose to spread the load of all apps.
If some producers, for any reason (failvover...), stick on node B and the consumers listen only on node A, i can imagine it's not a very healthy situation because messages should constantly be transfered from node B to node A.

Comment: As noted previously, there's nothing in the client that will automatically create a connection to each cluster node. The broker's clustering functionality was designed so that this isn't required. If you want this functionality you'll have to implement it yourself. The simplest solution probably would be to have an instance of your application to correspond with each node in the cluster. Any solution you implement will, of course, increase complexity on the client in order to deal with a situation the cluster will handle on its own. Again, I don't think this is a good approach.

Comment: Does your infra team understand that the broker's clustering functionality is designed so that it can redistribute and re-route messages to consumers to avoid starvation specifically so that clients don't have to care about the cluster topology?

Comment: Let me challenge this a bit further :)
- If i check the Artemis doc, there is a whole chapter about client-side load balancing ==>[Artemis doc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/).  It contradicts what you say when you say there is nothing in the client that will handle that.
- If i disable caching on the container listener, the connections spreads between all nodes but the connections are constantly closed/open and that's a problem.

Comment: - I eventually managed to get a situation with stable connections accoss all nodes using a JmsPoolConnectionFactory and disabling caching on DefaultMessageListenerContainer but i'm definitively not sure it's the right approach.
- the parameter useTopologyForLoadBalancing you can set in the connection string speaks by itself. The client is able to do load balancing by receiving the topology at the first connection (useTopologyForLoadBalancing=true) or by using the server list in the initial connection string (useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false). But it should be able to handle load balancing..

Comment: I think we're really talking about 2 different things. You can certainly use client-side connection load-balancing (i.e. CSLB) to spread connections created from the same JMS `ConnectionFactory` across different cluster nodes. I'm well aware of this feature given I implemented the `useTopologyForLoadBalancing` functionality. However, that's _not_ the kind of client ability I'm talking about, and it's _not_ the kind of thing that it seems to me that you really want. Using CSLB may provide you with something of a satisfactory "hack," but it's not designed for this use-case.

Comment: CSLB was designed with lots of individual clients in mind that would all be connecting to and disconnecting from the cluster throughout their life-cycles. By using CSLB these clients would receive the cluster topology and, by default, would create their next connection to a random node and thereafter would create connections in a round-robin fashion among the rest of the nodes in the topology. Given enough clients and enough connections everything should be relatively balanced across all the nodes. CSLB wasn't made for a single app to create individual connections to every node in the cluster.

Comment: The main trouble is that you have no clear visibility about what node you're connecting to or how many nodes the cluster even has. With CSLB you don't even know how many connections to actually create to get a connection to every node in the cluster. Keep in mind that clusters can grow and shrink dynamically. Perhaps that's not an issue in your case, but it's a problem in the general case and one that CSLB doesn't solve.

Comment: Furthermore, each application will have to create and manage their own connections to each node in the cluster which is significantly more complex than having a single connection or a node-agnostic pool of connections. Again, this is why the cluster is designed to redistribute and re-route messages so that clients don't have to deal with this complexity.

Comment: If, for some reason, you decide to just create a connection every time you receive a message as a kind of brute force way to use CSLB to consume all the messages on all the nodes then you can get into a particularly pathological situation where the messages are redistributed among nodes following the consumer as it hops around the cluster resulting in more total redistribution than if the consumer just stayed connected to a single node.

Comment: Lol, if i knew you were an Artemis dev, i wouldn't have challenged you :D
Quite interresting anyway. Thx for your explanations that make things more clear!

Anyway, i've got a last question.  My app runs in a K8S(Openshift) cluster. So,it's very easy for me to scale horizontally.  Doing so, i noticed that if i spawn a new instance of my app, the connections of the new app instance will, each time, target the other node of the Artemis cluster (in test env, cluster is made out of 2 nodes).  Is it by chance? or is it that the cluster can provide some infos to the client to target another node?